# How to make IIS 7 application pool run under an AD account?

Tags: active-directory, iis-7, file-permissions

I have an internal company web application that needs read permissions on certain folders in our LAN. The permissions on these folders are controlled by our Active Directory server. Since by default the application pool runs as a local machine account, it doesn't have any permissions on any folders. I've tried the following:

Right click on application pool->advanced settings->Identity->Custom Account

I've tried changing that to my own login, as well as a custom account I created in AD for that application pool, and both times I get an error that says, "The specified password is invalid. Type a new password". I'm completely sure I'm typing the correct password in both cases.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or is there an alternative way to grant the default application pool identity read permission on LAN folders?

Comment: A couple things to check - Ensure the account password is not expired or set to change at next logon; if the account is in a different domain than the server, specify the user name as domain\user.

Comment: Thank you! The server IIS is on _is_ in the domain, but adding domain\user did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to check

- Ensure the account password is not expired or set to change at next logon;
- if the account is in a different domain than the server, specify the user name as domain\user.