# IIS server which needs to be moved to workgroup from domain

Tags: iis

I have IIS server which is in DMZ and configured in domain. Now the same need to be moved to workgroup but as soon as we do it, the application using the IIS server goes down.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your application pool is running on a Domain account, like the opposite of: [How to make IIS 7 application pool run under an AD account?](https://serverfault.com/questions/516957/how-to-make-iis-7-application-pool-run-under-an-ad-account)